# Prototype for array locator functions

Tags: function, constraints, system-verilog

I am thinking of creating a generic task/function which will read a transaction from any given ovm analysis port and if the transaction matches some constraint provided by user then i will fire an event that matching transaction found.

I want the user to pass the constraint like we pass it with array locator functions using the with clause like

```
out = arr.find_first with (item == 10);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `with` clause in many of SystemVerilog's constructs is not very OOP friendly. There is no way to pass the `with` expression as an argument.

Two software design patterns you may want to try is

- the factory -  where you allow the user to extend these functions with a difference compare function
- a policy class - you can make class whose sole purpose is to provide a compare function.

Comment: Is there a way to pass the difference compare function as a parameter? Like we pass function pointers in C.

Comment: That exactly what you would do with a policy class.